# Spring Boot 1.5.3 web application terminate immediately after started

Tags: maven, spring-boot

After started the Spring Boot Project running on 1.5.3.RELEASE the logs running then force stop

Anyone have any idea why 1.5.3 is stop, I tried 1.4.6 The started successfully

Pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Logs

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-
compile @ demo >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Workspace\spring\demo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ demo <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-05-10 15:25:09.638  INFO 11112 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on WutikornMat with PID 11112 (D:\Workspace\sp
ring\demo\target\classes started by sutee.cha in D:\Workspace\spring\demo)
2017-05-10 15:25:09.643  INFO 11112 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-10 15:25:09.739  INFO 11112 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigAppli
cationContext@3a723bfc: startup date [Wed May 10 15:25:09 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-10 15:25:10.599  INFO 11112 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-10 15:25:10.617  INFO 11112 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 1.599 seconds (JVM running for 5.332)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.069 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-10T15:25:10+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/398M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-10 15:25:10.751  INFO 11112 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicat
ionContext@3a723bfc: startup date [Wed May 10 15:25:09 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-10 15:25:10.754  INFO 11112 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Then I run the jar via command line outside IDE

```
2017-05-10 15:38:57.630  INFO 7532 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on WutikornMat with PID 7532 (D
:\Workspace\spring\demo\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by sutee.cha in D:\Workspace\spring\demo\target)
2017-05-10 15:38:57.638  INFO 7532 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-10 15:38:57.765  INFO 7532 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplic
ationContext@255316f2: startup date [Wed May 10 15:38:57 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-10 15:38:58.973  INFO 7532 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-10 15:38:58.997  INFO 7532 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 1.888 seconds (JVM running for 2.455)
2017-05-10 15:38:59.000  INFO 7532 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicati
onContext@255316f2: startup date [Wed May 10 15:38:57 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-10 15:38:59.003  INFO 7532 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

So you can see the Setup and Example is exactly the same as [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_moving_to_production)

What I missed on 1.5.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the log?

Comment: Posted, or you need full debug I'll make it for you

Comment: what happens if you start your app outside of your IDE? `java -jar DemoApplication.jar` in your command line?

Comment: It's showing the same logs as edited

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [current example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-code) there is no `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, but

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {
```

This runs out of the box. If I start your example, I get

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
```

If I move the class from the default package to any package - let's say `demo` - the application starts correctly.

Comment: I moved the Controller out to com.demo package, nothing change.

Comment: Hmm, if I move it to a package it starts right away both from IDE and from command line using `java -jar`.  You build it with `maven clean install` and start the built jar using `java -jar ...`, is that correct? Otherwise how are your building and starting the application?

Comment: Is it just the described code, or is there anything else? Could you provide a gist?

Comment: I ran both in IDE and Command Line after moved the Class to another package named as demo, which the default package is example, I think this is all the described from example. 1 thing I added @SpringBootApplication annotation in the class. Anyway I removed it still not working